# PhpStorm and SVN: Setting DEVelopment and PRODuction environments

Tags: php, svn, phpstorm

I have developed a Client-Server Android app using Eclipse for the client and PHP with Zend Framework for the server side.

For the server side, I have a development environment and a production one. I've been developing all the server side with Notepad++ in my local machine, then I upload it to Dev, test and then I change some code (paths, etc) and upload it to Prod.

Now, I want to do things better, so I am trying to use PhpStorm and SVN version control. My question is: How can I work with PhpStorm using SVN repository and differencing between DEV and PROD environments easily?